# How can I log into an Okta enabled site using curl?

Tags: authentication, curl, okta

I'm trying to use curl to log into an **Okta-enabled** site providing the user name & password using the parameter *-u {username:password}* and all I get back is the html content of the Okta redirect page.
How can I login into the app by providing my Okta credentials using **curl**?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following script, assuming you have installed jq (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download):

```
sessionToken=$(curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type:
application/json" -d '{
"username": "[okta_username]",
"password": "[password]",
"options": {
"multiOptionalFactorEnroll": true,
 "warnBeforePasswordExpired": true
}  
}' "https://[yourorg].oktapreview.com/api/v1/authn" | jq '.sessionToken' -r)
```

```
 curl -X GET "https://[yourorg].oktapreview.com/login/sessionCookieRedirect?token=${sessionToken}&redirectUrl=http://blah" -c "okta-cookie"
```

```
 curl -X GET [OKTA_EMBED_LINK] -b "okta-cookie" -L -v
```

From the last line, you will need to grab the SAMLResponse form parameter and submit it to the action url of the same form.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Is there any other way that doesn't require you to request a url that has /api/v1/authn in it? If I query that one using a web browser I get 

E0000022: The endpoint does not support the provided HTTP method

which suggests that my org doesn't support it.

Comment: @Giuseppe that's because in the browser you are doing a GET and the endpoint requires POST

Comment: How to grab and submit the SAMLResponse form parameter in the last line?  Could you provide a little more detail?

Comment: I found that my curl call would result in an error of "The request body was not well-formed. (E0000003). With some experimentation, I realised that was rejecting my request due to those extra padding spaces and carriage returns within the -d'...' argument. Once I removed them (e.g., `-d'{"username":"name","password":"pwd",etc}'`), my curl call was successful.